# Issue compiling app - React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to compile a react native module that I am working on. I think the issue is that instead of having `/android/src/main/java...` I have `/android/TeamCode/src/main/java`. If this is the case, how would I go about making it so that react native looks in `/android/TeamCode/src` instead of `/android/src`? However I don't know if this is the issue, and I could be completely wrong.

#### Structure

Here is what my project looks like:

```
- module 
--- index.js
--- package.json
--- android //this is where the below screenshot is from
----- build.gradle
----- TeamCode
------- build.gradle //apply from: '../build.common.gradle'
--- Example //this is the app I am trying to compile
----- index.android.js
----- android
----- package-lock.json
----- other stuff
```

#### Error

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
/Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/MainApplication.java:6: error: package com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller does not exist
import com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller.MyPackage;
                                      ^
/Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/MainApplication.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            new MyPackage()
                ^
  symbol: class MyPackage
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### module/example/package.json

```
{
    "name": "Example",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.47.2",
        "ftcnative": "file:../"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.1",
        "jest": "20.0.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

#### module/index.js

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.MyModule;
```

#### android/build.common.gradle

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile rootProject.file('libs/ftc.debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19

        /**
         * We keep the versionCode and versionName of robot controller applications in sync with
         * the master information published in the AndroidManifest.xml file of the FtcRobotController
         * module. This helps avoid confusion that might arise from having multiple versions of
         * a robot controller app simultaneously installed on a robot controller device.
         *
         * We accomplish this with the help of a funky little Groovy script that maintains that
         * correspondence automatically.
         *
         * @see <a href="http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html">Configure Your Build</a>
         * @see <a href="http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html">Versioning Your App</a>
         */
        def manifestFile = project(':FtcRobotController').file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml');
        def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
        //
        def vCodePattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+(\\.\\d+)*)\"")
        def matcher = vCodePattern.matcher(manifestText)
        matcher.find()
        def vCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
        //
        def vNamePattern = Pattern.compile("versionName=\"(.*)\"")
        matcher = vNamePattern.matcher(manifestText);
        matcher.find()
        def vName = matcher.group(1)
        //
        versionCode vCode
        versionName vName
    }

    // Advanced user code might just want to use Vuforia directly, so we set up the libs as needed
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Disable debugging for release versions so it can be uploaded to Google Play.
            //debuggable true
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir rootProject.file('libs')
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs rootProject.file('libs')
    }
}

apply from: 'build.release.gradle'
```

#### android/build.gradle

```
/**
 * Top-level build file for ftc_app project.
 *
 * It is extraordinarily rare that you will ever need to edit this file.
 */

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'TeamCode/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

- when I add `java.srcDirs += 'android/TeamCode/src/main/java'` I get:

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  - What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':ftcnative:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

    > Unable to find source java class: '/Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/android/TeamCode/src/main/java/org/firstinspires/ftc/teamcode/MyModule.java' because it does not belong to any of the source dirs: '[/Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/node_modules/ftcnative/android/src/main/java, /Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/node_modules/ftcnative/android/TeamCode/src/main/java, /Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/node_modules/ftcnative/android/src/release/java, /Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/node_modules/ftcnative/android/build/generated/source/r/release, /Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/node_modules/ftcnative/android/build/generated/source/buildConfig/release, /Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/node_modules/ftcnative/android/build/generated/source/aidl/release, /Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/node_modules/ftcnative/android/build/generated/source/rs/release]'
- when I add `java.srcDirs += 'android/TeamCode/src/main/java'` I still get the first error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know React Native, but in Android, to do this you have to change your build.gradle. Find the `android` section, and add a `sourceSets` section like so:

```
android {
    //...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            // Like this...
            java.srcDirs += 'TeamCode/src/main/java'
            // ...or maybe, like that...
            java.srcDirs += 'android/TeamCode/src/main/java'
            // Dirty, extreme alternative...
            java.srcDirs += '/Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/android/TeamCode/src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that this is **adding** an additional source directory (because of the `+=`).

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately that did not work, the second one produced the same error as above and the first gave me this error:  `Unable to find source java class: '/Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/android/TeamCode/src/main/java/org/firstinspires/ftc/teamcode/MyModule.java' because it does not belong to any of the source dirs: '[/Users/zoe/saas/robotics/ftcnative/Example/node_modules/ftcnative/android/src/main/java, ...`

Comment: Could you update your question with the complete error message? Also, add the location of your two gradle files.

Comment: I have added the two gradle files and added the full error. Thanks for the help. would it be helpful if I linked a repo with my full project?

Comment: Does TeamCode/build.gradle only have the `apply from: '../build.common.gradle'` line? If so, the `sourceSet` change should go to build.common.gradle, I think.

Comment: same issue (the original error) even after adding it to build.common.gradle

Comment: Maybe it's stupid to ask, but have you done a clean between tests? Additionally, is there some kind of hard link or symbolic link in the project?

Comment: Yes, I have done a clean build between tests. Also, there is a link. I am not sure what type, I just used react-native link

Comment: I've updated my answer to use absolute path. It's not pretty, but at least it would allow to see if path is being added to the `sourceSet`.

Comment: I just completely re-built the project, I still have no idea what the issue was, but it seemed to be fixed when I re-built it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after changing the name of one of my java methods.

I solved it by:

> Deleting my android build folder and running `react-native run-android` again.